# write files and zip its from byte arrays

Tags: java, zip

I'm trying to write some files inside zip file and download it.

When my first file is wrote, zip file start downloading... but others files aren't there.

```
public static void addToZipFile(List<byte[]> contentFiles, List<String> strDocFileNames, HttpServletResponse response) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {


    String strDocFileName = null;
    byte [] contentFile = null;
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=test.zip");

    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

    try  {

    for (int i = 0; i < strDocFileNames.size(); i++) {
        strDocFileName = strDocFileNames.get(i);
        contentFile = contentFiles.get(i);


        ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(strDocFileName);
        e.setSize(contentFile.length);
        e.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        out.putNextEntry(e);

        out.write(contentFile);
        out.closeEntry();

    }

        out.flush();
        out.close();



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }   
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: If that code is throwing an exception, you'll never know since you're swallowing exceptions. Why? Why not log them or at least print them out?

Comment: e.g., `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Yes, I changed but no exception ...